# DevToolsProtocol, Runtime.evaluate against worker execution context

Tags: javascript, chrome-devtools-protocol

In the console of chrome devtools there is a dropdown at the top to select the execution context.

Here is an example when on [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

[image]

Changing the execution context changes the available global variables and what any console invoked .js can access

I'm trying to run some javascript via ChromeDevtools Protocol using the  [Runtime.evaluate](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Runtime/#method-evaluate) function and I need to run it in the worker context.

Checking the [CDP docs](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol), I see that `Runtime.evaluate` takes a parameter `ExecutionContextId`. I initially made the assumption that the execution contexts via the DevTools window dropdown would be the same as this parameter. The only way I've worked out how to get a list of the the current `ExecutionContextId`'s is to subscribe to the `Runtime.executionContextCreated` event then do a `Runtime.disable` followed by a `Runtime.enable` which causes an `ExecutionContextDiscription` to be received by the eventhandler for each loaded context.

However after looking though the `ExecutionContextDescription`'s returned, some match those in the dropdown, but an execution context describing the worker is never returned.

How does one execute js in a worker execution context via CDP, as is trivially done in ChromeDevtools window ?

Comment: Ugh, I am just having exactly the same issue. I also need to run a runtime command on a service worker, but I don't know the context ID. Did you figure something out? Giving this one a bounty to attract more attention.

Comment: did you try `Target.getTargets`? every target has `browserContextId` in `TargetInfo`.

Comment: @Juraj maybe, One of the `TargetInfo`'s returned (in my test here) is a SharedWorker, but the `browserContextId` is string (eg. `3EE21C36701BE09DB05708AAA333FB86` and `ExecutionContextId` is supposed to be `integer`. How to go from one to the other ?

Comment: there is an alternative parameter for executionContextId as string, but `evaluate` doesn't accept browserContextId there. I didn't find a way. the only way I see to get executionContextId is what you describe in the question or Page.createIsolatedWorld

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst I did not find a way to do it with an execution context, I was able to achieve the end game via the below process.

1. Get a list of the possible `TargetID`'s
2. Connect to the Target of interest with `Target.attachToTarget` & note the `sessionId` returned
3. Call the CDP method of interest in "flat mode"

Step 1 has a couple of approaches, and each additional step here may need to be applied in different situations.

1. Call `Target.getTargets` which may return the target of interest
2. Hook into the `targetCreated` event and call `Target.setDiscoverTargets`
3. Call `Target.setAutoAttach(true, false)` before step 2
4. Call `Target.setAutoAttach(false, false)` before step 3

In my testing here, the worker of interest did not appear via method 1, but does appears in method 2, and in other situations I needed all 4 steps for the event handler to properly fire. I don't know why there is a difference.

"Flat mode" as mentioned in the [docs](https://chromedevtools.github.io/) is basically any CDP command with a `sessionId` included. e.g.

`{"method": "Domain.method", "params": {"method params"}, "sessionId": "12345"}`

Credit goes to Puppeteer and its logs which helped me to decipher the process.

Comment: Could you perhaps make your answer a little bit more explicit? Did you use the auto-attach feature at all, and if so, did you use `waitForDebuggerOnStart`? If not, does this mean you don't care when `Runtime.evaluate` will be executed in the worker?

Comment: I could, but I think the answer covers the specifics that are directly related to getting to the point of `Runtime.evaluate` against the worker on the assumption the worker is already running (no need for auto-attach or `waitForDebuggerOnStart` in my testing). If there is some other complexity related to how a worker starts, then maybe some additional steps might be necessary ? But if the worker is not running then it would not even appear in the DevTools window context dropdown for adhoc js eval. Is the above not working in your case ?

Comment: In my specific case I not only need to attach to all workers that may be running, but also clear their caches (or, prevent them from using any caching) before they actually start working. I have tried running the respective command from the `Network` domain as well as `Runtime.evaluate` with the `chrome.benchmarking` commands that clear caches — but it doesn't seem to work (requests have the `fromDiskCache` flag set). Might be another issue though …

Comment: I've just updated my answer in light of some additional testing here. Turns out `setAutoAttach` is needed sometimes. If you can do a `Runtime.evaluate('this.location')` and inspect the details of the object it will give an indication if you are indeed running in the correct context. If you are, then the other issues you are experiencing are likely outside the scope of this question.